# AdAway and Xposed Framework unable to edit system files in a rooted Huawei Ascend Y330

Tags: root-access, huawei-ascend-y330

I rooted my Huawei Ascend Y330 using King Root (verified it with Root Checker). The problem started when I was trying to install AdAway and Xposed Framework. They both are unable to edit files. I already tried to change permissions with Root Explorer / Root Browser, but I keep getting the same error.

<sub>Screenshots of the errors (Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image] 
[image]